# Search and retrieve matching data from an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, logic

I have an array that contains some data as given below:

I'm trying to implement this such that based on the value passed, the corresponding result is shown. Eg If I pass **"test-1"**, it should return **test**, **test*** and **test-1**. It **should not** return **test-2 or test 3**

**Conditions:**

- If the exact input value matches something in the array, it should be added to the result
- If the value entered has a hyphen, then it should retrieve any other value that does not contain a hyphen and contains the text before the hyphen.

I thought of using regex but not sure if that is the best solution for this. My logic so far feels like it will end up being messy so I'll like to know know an elegant way of implementing this please.

This is what I have

```
const arrayList = ["test", "hello", "blessed", "blessed-9","test*", "test-1", "blessed*", "test-2", "hello*", "test-3" ];

let result = [];

function tester(inputVal){
    arrayList.filter(arrayVal => {
        if(arrayVal === inputVal){
            result.push(arrayVal);
        } else if(arrayVal.indexof('*') !== -1){
            //check if the first part matches 
        }
    })

    console.log(result,"====")
}

tester("test");
```

Comment: You have not made your conditions for matching clear.

Comment: I have added the conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single `.filter()` call on `arrayList` with the conditions that you specified.

Test if the values match.

If not, test if the value of the string before the hyphen matches the beginning of the element and that the element doesn't have a hyphen in it.

In the snippet the string value before the hyphen is retrieved by calling `string.split('-')` and getting the first result from the returned array.

```js
const arrayList = ["test", "hello", "blessed", "blessed-9","test*", "test-1", "blessed*", "test-2", "hello*", "test-3" ];


function filterArray(string) {
  let root = string.split('-')[0];
  return arrayList.filter(element => 
    element === string || 
    element.startsWith(root) && !element.includes('-'));
}

const result = filterArray('test-1');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arrayList = ["test", "hello", "blessed", "blessed-9","test*", "test-1", "blessed*", "test-2", "hello*", "test-3" ];
    
    let result = [];
    
    function tester(inputVal){
        result=[]
        arrayList.forEach(arrayVal => {
            if(arrayVal.search(inputVal)!=-1){
                result.push(arrayVal);
            }
        })
    
    console.log(result)
    }
    
    tester("test");
```